# How can I dump a loaded mib out of PHP

Tags: php, snmp

I loaded a mib into PHP with a ton of OIDs. I'd like some way to dump those out and run through them. I didn't find any way on the php website docs to do that.

Comment: This seems more like a question for StackOverflow.com?

Answer (score 0):

If you loaded it into a PHP variable you can dum it via

```
print_r($var);
```

If not: Could you provide some code, so we can see how you load them into PHP?

Answer (score 0):

try the [SNMP](http://php.net/manual/de/book.snmp.php) extension.

there is a function called [snmp_read_mib](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.snmp-read-mib.php) which could be the right for you.

i think the package is called `php5-snmp`.